# Use Jupyter notebook without DataBricks in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-data-factory

I gather from the documentation that we can use Jupyter notebooks only with Databricks Spark cluster.

Is there a way around this? Can I call Jupyter notebook as an activity from ADF without Databricks environment? I would like to have a simple way to call some python code from ADF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Custom Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) in ADF. Custom activity supports cmd command, so you can use command line to invoke python script.

And there's another example of using python in custom activity:
https://github.com/rawatsudhir1/ADFPythonCustomActivity

Hope it helps.